# How to retrieve saved device tokens from realtime database and send notification to them using firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notification to small group of devices so I want to use "SendToDevice" option in firebase cloud function. I am not familiar with javascript, so please help me to retrieve tokens from firebase realtime database and send notification to them.

Structure of device token stored in my database, those keys are the tokens:

```
{   
 "tokens" : {
    "-KdD1f0ecmVXHZ3H3abZ" : {
      "token" : "true",
    },
    "-KdG4iHEYjInv7ljBhgG" : {
      "token" : "true",
    }
}
```

> Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path:
>   "/shopdata/${shopKey/${acYear}/notestokens/${sectionKey}". Paths must
>   be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

I tried by removing those dollar symbol but again I am getting log message that "There are no notification tokens to send to."

Here my code :

```
exports.sendClassNotesNotification = functions.database.ref('/shopdata/{shopKey}/{year}/notes/{sectionKey}').onWrite(event => {

  const shopdata = event.params.shopdata;
  const year = event.params.year;
  const sectionKey = event.params.sectionKey;

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.

  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref('/shopdata/${shopKey/${year}/notestokens/${sectionKey}').once('value');

    return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]).then(results => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];

    // Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Section Note',
        body: `You have new note`
      }
    };

    // Listing all tokens.
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, remember you have to return the promise from .once('value').

```
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/groupchat/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {
    return admin.database().ref('/tokens/...refrence...').once('value')
                    .then(function(tokensSnapshot){
        const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'App Name',
                body: "New Message",
                sound: "default"
            }   
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    });
});
```

For working code sample, head out the the official samples repository [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js).